# token generation in firebase for agora io 1on 1 video chat for android kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, agora.io

I am developing an android app using firebase as a server and agora video stream platform for the 1 on 1 video chat. The app working with the temporary token given by the agora. But agora wants me to generate token from the server to use app in production. I do not have any server for my app. I just use the firebase platform.

Is it possible to generate token for agora using firebase platform?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a full backend server, you could run this using [Firebase Cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/products/functions).

The Agora token generation does not require an always on server, just to be deployed on an infrastructure you control as a developer so that you can connect it with your user-management system so that you as a developer have more control over which users can generate tokens and connect to channels and communicate with users.

[I've written this guide on deploying a Golang web service](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/agora-token-service) but you can adapt it to a cloud function.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is helpful but I do not know how to adapt this to firebase cloud functions. Can you help me plaese? thanks again

Comment: @kadiryapar Did you ever figure this out?  same question!

Comment: yes, I figured it out but not on firebase, on the server.